# ReactNative Отрендерить svg картинку, полученную с помощью API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Всем привет!

Мне нужно отрендерить список из телефонного кода страны, названия страны и ее флага. Для этого я использую следующий эндпоинт:
`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`.

Картинки приходят в виде строки в svg формате. Я использую SvgUri для отображения svg картинки и передаю правильно формат, только вот сама картинка не отображается. Тоже самое с компонентом Image. Подскажите, как мне отрендерить svg картинку, которую я получаю в API?

Когда я выполняю нижепривденный код, то получаю следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функция для запроса (FetchCountries.js);

```
const URI = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2';

export default {
    async fetchUsers() {
        try {
            let response = await fetch(URI + '/all');
            let responseJsonData = await response.json();
            return responseJsonData;
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Сам компонент, отображающий список:

```
class CountryPicker extends React.Component {

    state = {
        users: []
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const users = await fetchedCountries.fetchUsers();
        this.setState({users});
        console.log(this.state);
    }


    render() {
        const {isVisible, onSelect} = this.props;
        return (
            <Modal
                style={styles.modal}
                isVisible={isVisible}
                backdropOpacity={0.30}
                useNativeDriver={true}
            >
                <View style={styles.window}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.users}
                        renderItem={({item}) => (
                            <TouchableHighlight
                                onPress={() => onSelect(item.name)}
                                underlayColor={colors.lightGrey}>
                                <View style={styles.listItem}>
                                    <Text style={styles.listItemText}>
                                        {item.country}
                                    </Text>
                                    <SvgUri
                                        width="30"
                                        height="30"
                                        source={{uri: item.flag}}
                                    />
                                </View>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        )}>
                    </FlatList>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: День добрый, Денис. На SOru принято задавать вопросы на русском (:

Comment: @Suvitruf Здравствуйте! Исправил вопрос